# R replace multiple columns by merging another data

Tags: r, merge

I want to replace mupltiple columns by merging another data. 
For example: I have two data frames, I want to replace columns of `dat2` by using `dat1`.

```
  set.seed(1234)
  dat1 = data.frame(userId = c(1:10), value = sample(100, 10))
  #    userId value
  # 1       1    84
  # 2       2    29
  # 3       3    27
  # 4       4    19
  # 5       5    23
  # 6       6    31
  # 7       7    99
  # 8       8    15
  # 9       9     4
  # 10     10    20

  dat2 = data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2 = 10:6, var3 = sample(10, 5))
  #   var1 var2 var3
  # 1    1   10    7
  # 2    2    9    5
  # 3    3    8    3
  # 4    4    7   10
  # 5    5    6    2
```

Expected output:

```
  # > dat2
  #   var1 var2 var3
  # 1   84   20   99
  # 2   29    4   23
  # 3   27   15   27
  # 4   19   99   20
  # 5   23   31   29
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lapply` with `match`

```
as.data.frame(lapply(dat2,FUN = function(x) dat1$value[match(x,dat1$userId)]))
  var1 var2 var3
1   12   47    1
2   62   99   83
3   60   22   60
4   61    1   47
5   83   97   62
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unstack` and `stack`

```
unstack(transform(stack(dat2),n=dat1$value[match(values,dat1$userId)]),n~ind)
  var1 var2 var3
1   12   47    1
2   62   99   83
3   60   22   60
4   61    1   47
5   83   97   62
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `base R` option is

```
dat2[] <- with(dat1, setNames(value, userId)[as.matrix(dat2)])
dat2
#  var1 var2 var3
#1   12   47    1
#2   62   99   83
#3   60   22   60
#4   61    1   47
#5   83   97   62
```